# How do I tell Camel that I will end the message processing myself

Tags: apache-camel

I am writing a component (an endpoint) that will receive the Camel `Exchange` like this:

`from("file|activemq|whatever").to(myEndpoint);`

Upon receiving, I want it to pass the exchange to a set of subroutines, which may work asynchronously, and which will eventually decide that they have finished, possibly composed a response in an Out message of the `Exchange`. All may happen outside the Camel Context, I am working only with the `Exchange` object.

Then my subroutines should invoke something that will tell Camel that it should propagate the response back, do other stuff as per the source and middle components requirements (for example, if it is a `file:/`, rename a file) and consider the routing ow this Exchange completed.

I was thinking that I would invoke the `Exchange`'s Uint of Work `done` method.

Unfortunately I am noticing that Camel still tries to end the exchange by itself too, in wrong time and state. For example, for file source, it fails to rename the file which already has been removed.

Here is some of my code:

Here I define an endpoint:

```
        _proceeder = new DefaultEndpoint() {

            private final String _defaultUri = "rex:producer-" + UUID.randomUUID().toString();

            @Override
            protected String createEndpointUri() {
                return _defaultUri;
            }

            @Override
            public Producer createProducer() throws Exception {

                return new DefaultAsyncProducer(this) {

                    @Override
                    public boolean process(final Exchange exchange1, final AsyncCallback callback) {

                        final ExchangeWrapper exchange = new ExchangeWrapper(_uri, exchange1, MessageSystem.this);
                        _LOG.debug("Got input for {}. Processing...", _uri);

                        exchange._taken(); // 1. all subsequent will increase by 1

                        /// some majick....

                        final boolean done = exchange._released(); // if all were released immediately, itll be 0 and sent back now. otherwise the last to release will send it back.

                        if (done) {
                            _LOG.debug("Processed input for {} synchronously", _uri);

                            //callback.done(true);
                        } else {
                            _LOG.debug("Processed input for {} asynchronously, awaiting response", _uri);

                            //exchange1.addOnCompletion(new Synchronization() {
                            //    @Override
                            //    public void onComplete(Exchange exchange) {
                            //        onFailure(exchange);
                            //    }
                            //

                            //    @Override
                            //    public void onFailure(Exchange exchange) {
                            //        callback.done(false);
                            //    }
                            //});

                        }

                        return done;
                    }
                };

            }

            @Override
            public Consumer createConsumer(Processor processor) throws Exception {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isSingleton() {
                return true;
            }
        };

        _proceeder.setCamelContext(context);
```

Needless to say that I don't understand why I am given an AsyncCallback in my `DefaultAsyncProducer.process()` method; regardless of me calling its `done()` method, the system doesn't see this and still ends the exchange by itself once more. But it is not the question.

here is the ExchangeWrapper `_released` and `_done` methods:

```
    private void _done() throws Exception {
        UnitOfWork uow = _exchange.getUnitOfWork();
        uow.done(_exchange);
        //try{
        //    uow.stop();
        //}catch(Exception e){
        //    
        //}
        _exchange.setUnitOfWork(null);
    }

    private boolean _released() {
        final boolean ret;
        final int cnt;
        final int trancnt;
        synchronized (_exchange) {
            cnt = _exchange.getProperty("rex.takenCount", Integer.class) - 1;
            _exchange.setProperty("rex.takenCount", cnt);
            trancnt = _exchange.getProperty("rex.takenAsTransient", Integer.class);
        }

        if (_LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
            _LOG.debug("Input for {} released. {} times left, {} transient", new Object[]{_exchange.getProperty("rex.uri", String.class), cnt, trancnt});
        }
        if (cnt <= 0 || cnt <= trancnt) {

            if (_LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
                _LOG.debug("Message for {} is processed by all non-transient receivers. Setting done...", new Object[]{_exchange.getProperty("rex.uri", String.class)});
            }
            _done();
            ret = true;
            if (_LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
                _LOG.debug("Message for {} is set done", new Object[]{_exchange.getProperty("rex.uri", String.class)});
            }

        } else {
            ret = false;
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

So basically I wrap the `Exchange` to keep state and decide when the processing should be stopped.

While digging into the Camel internals I've seen some similar counters that keep track of how many times the `Exchange` has been taken for processing, but I'd like to be in control, thus my own wrapper.

So what should I call instead of

```
        _exchange.getUnitOfWork().done(_exchange);
```

**to tell the Camel Internal Processor and others that there is no need to mark the exchange done because I am doing it?**

My latest finding is to call `uow.stop();` so that it clears all the 'after' processors etc, but I suddenly understood that I may try and hack Camel myself for a long time, but it's better to ask people who know exactly what to do without trying and guessing.

These are the examples of my Routes:

```
        RouteBuilder rb = new RouteBuilder(_context) {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                if (_tokenizer != null) {
                    from(_uri).split().method(_tokenizer, "tokenizeReader").streaming().to(_proceeder);
                } else {
                    from(_uri).to(_proceeder);
                }
            }
        };
```

If I could avoid building routes, instantiating endpoints and producers, and employ standalone processors, I'd happily do, but I don't want to ditch what the marvelous Camel project has to offer in terms of splitting, streaming, marshalling etc etc; and all of this seems to be built around routes.

Comment: Not sure I follow, but is there something missing in Camel that you want to do this like this?`I mean why not use OnCompletion() if you want to take action after the route is completed?

Comment: Better to say I want a route wait for something I do with the message and then complete, because I may want the response to be sent back to the route starting point.

Comment: So why not use a direct: in memory queue to do whatever you do like "rename a file or whatever else" and then return some message? If you want async request/response rather than reinvent something wouldn't it better to use queuing app instead?

Comment: That's how the task is put. Thanks, I'll consider all these options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be I am not clear with what are you trying to achieve with this, but let me try.

> Upon receiving, I want it to pass the exchange to a set of
>   subroutines, which may work asynchronously, and which will eventually
>   decide that they have finished

So for this you can write a [processor](http://camel.apache.org/processor.html) and configure it at the end of your route .Within your processor you can use a thread pool, submit to it the subroutine tasks, wait for their completion and decide if you want to change the message body ( correct way explained [here](http://camel.apache.org/using-getin-or-getout-methods-on-exchange.html) with a good diagram explaining flow of an exchange through a route) and camel will automatically take care of returning the response to the caller of the route based on exchange [pattern](http://camel.apache.org/exchange-pattern.html). For example in your case if the route begins from file/activemq route then it is event based/one way exchange and no response will be sent to the caller as there is no caller client as such. It will be just an event which will initiate the exchange.

**Update  :**
For using the async processing feature in camel for enhanced scalability take a look at [this](https://github.com/camelinaction/camelinaction2/tree/master/chapter13/scalability) example with code from the highly recommended [Camel in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/camel-in-action) book

Comment: Thanks! Does this mean that a thread will be waiting until I do everything I wanted, in other words, my `Processor` will not finish until my subroutines finish? If so, I was thinking about it, and didn't like it as there could be  a considerable amount of time until my procedures finish their job with the exchange.

Comment: The `DefaultAsyncProducer` seems to do what I want but I can't figure out how. Probably I need to remove the "uow done" thing from my exchange wrapper...

Comment: If your worry is the unpredictable and  long processing time which may hurt scalability, then you can make use of AsyncProcessing. Take a look at an example here https://github.com/camelinaction/camelinaction2/tree/master/chapter13/scalability

Comment: Thanks for the links! Will try to derive answer to my question from there.